# How to dynamically display php content based on link

Tags: php, jquery

I would like to replicate this site's glossary function: https://www.mortgageloan.com/finance-glossary-terms

Objective: Click on a letter and content corresponding to that letter will be shown. Click on another letter, and only the clicked letter's content is shown.

I have my dictionary.php file with an array setup like this:

```
$dictionary = array(
    'A'=>array(
        'Term1'=>'Definition1',
        'Term2'=>'Definition2',
    ),
    'B'=>array(
        'Term1'=>'Definition1',
        'Term2'=>'Definition2',
    ),
);
```

I can display the Terms and Definitions fine with a foreach loop, but it displays all the terms and definitions. How can I display the terms and definitions pertaining to only their corresponding letters when the user clicks on that letter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The site you linked doesn't seem to use AJAX like @JeremyE suggests. It just loads a bunch of "tabs" (one for each letter) and then lets you switch between them as demonstrated [here](https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/w3css_tabulators.asp). It still loads all the data at once, just hides parts.

#### The Menu Bar

This loops through each letter in `$dictionary` and adds it as a button

```
<div>
    <?php foreach($dictionary as $letter => $terms) { ?>
        <button onclick="openTab('<?= $letter ?>')"><?= $letter ?></button>
    <?php } ?>
</div>
```

#### The Tabs:

This generates a tab for each letter in `$dictionary` and then creates a paragraph for each term within that.

```
<?php foreach($dictionary as $letter => $terms) { ?>

    <div class="tab" id="<?= $letter ?>" style="display: none;">

        <?php foreach($terms as $term => $def) { ?>
            <p><?= $term . " is: " . $def;?></p>
        <?php } ?>

    </div>
<?php } ?>
```

#### JS to add functionality

This JS function simply shows a tab with a certain ID, and hides all the others. It's called by the buttons inside the Menu.

```
<script>
function openTab(tab) {
    var i;
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("tab");

    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        x[i].style.display = "none";
    }

    document.getElementById(tab).style.display = "block";
}
</script>
```

This gives you the basic structure of how it's done.

Comment: This is great! I've looked into the w3schools link you provided and I've got my code to work as well, however what is currently happening is when I click on a letter to display its glossary, only the first term is set to "block" while the rest of the terms under that letter is set to "none".

Comment: @the_fez You shouldn't be setting `display` on any of the *terms*, you only need to set it for the *tab* that's around them

Comment: I wasn't setting a display on the terms. I have the _tab_ id around the _terms_ like you have above, but for some reason only one definition is being shown. When I inspected the element in Chrome, the other terms were getting set as "none".

Comment: @the_fex There might be something elsewhere (not in your question) adding the `display="none"`. The code I posted works for me (just tried it again).

Comment: I'm an idiot. -___- I had the outer div inside the nested for-loop instead of having: `outer div > for-loop > div w/ terms and def`. Thanks so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how you are calling it, so my answer may need to be fined tuned depending on the call, but if you are sending an AJAX request to the dictionary.php file with information about the letter that was clicked, the php file could look something like this (in simple fashion):

```
$letter = $_REQUEST['letter']  // Retrieve value for key 'letter'

foreach ($dictionary[$letter] as $term => $def) {  // Loop through terms in the dictionary for only the letter clicked
   echo $term . ": " . $def . " ";  // Print each term followed by its definition
}
```

If you aren't sending any information to the php file currently (which is possible since you said you were just looping through their entire dictionary), you would need to use something called an AJAX request in order to give the php file information about what letter was clicked. That would look like this in jQuery:

```
let letterClicked = "A"  // Change this to the location of the letter information in the clicked element (could be element.value or element.innerhtml)

$.get("dictionary.php", { letter: letterClicked }, function ( data ) {
     // Do something with the data that is returned
})
```

I hope that helped! Let me know if you have any more information about the problem that would help refine my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I'm calling the dictionary.php file that I have by just doing an "include" and using a foreach loop to loop through the terms and definitions. I've heard of AJAX and seen it a little bit, but I'm looking for something more simplistic. Thanks again!

Comment: Yeah, as @Xuzrus pointed out I was off the mark about what exactly you wanted—my mind went immediately to how to receive the right information from the dictionary.php file (just receiving one set of terms, not all sets) rather than how to store all the information (and display it) separately. I'm glad you got some help and figured it out :)